# R: How to swap values in a data frame with condition?

Tags: r

My dataset has 2 IDs respectively from a parent and a child but I don't know which is who. I have however their age
This is the table I am working with:

```
ID1 ID2 sex1 sex2 age1 age2
1   8   9    1    2   44   11
2  17   7    1    1   56   76
3   1  44   NA   NA   16   55
4   3  13   NA   NA   NA   NA
5  55   6    2   NA   56   10
6   4  33    2   NA   45   9
7   2  66    1   NA   12   45
8  72  99   NA   NA   NA   NA
9  12  11    2    2   30   12
```

By using an  `if` statement, I want to identify who's who according to their age.
Here is the code I made but it is not working:

```
install.packages('seqinr')
library(seqinr)

for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  if (data$age2[i]> data$age1[i]){
    swap(data$age1[i], data$age2[i])
  }
}
```

The error message:

```
Error in if (data$age2[i] > data$age1[i]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I want to put the parents' age in age1 and the child's age in age2.
Does someone has a better idea on how to do it?

Comment: I believe the error is because you have NAs. If I To get around this, you could do something like `data <- data[complete.cases(data[c("age1","age2")]), ]`. If you want to handle NAs in a special way, can you include the expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
You can manage it without any for loop, in case you only need to put the highest value in `age1`, and the lower value in `age2`, comparing by row the two columns:

```
# I've put age_* to compare results with data, to replace, use age* in df$age*
df$age_1 <- pmax(df$age1, df$age2)
df$age_2 <- pmin(df$age1, df$age2)
```

With result:

```
  ID1 ID2 sex1 sex2 age1 age2 age_1 age_2
1   8   9    1    2   44   11    44    11
2  17   7    1    1   56   76    76    56
3   1  44   NA   NA   16   55    55    16
4   3  13   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
5  55   6    2   NA   56   10    56    10
6   4  33    2   NA   45    9    45     9
7   2  66    1   NA   12   45    45    12
8  72  99   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA
9  12  11    2    2   30   12    30    12
```

---

With data:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'ID1 ID2 sex1 sex2 age1 age2
1   8   9    1    2   44   11
2  17   7    1    1   56   76
3   1  44   NA   NA   16   55
4   3  13   NA   NA   NA   NA
5  55   6    2   NA   56   10
6   4  33    2   NA   45   9
7   2  66    1   NA   12   45
8  72  99   NA   NA   NA   NA
9  12  11    2    2   30   12', header = T)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's way easier that way!

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table(
  "ID1 ID2 sex1 sex2 age1 age2
   8   9    1    2   44   11
  17   7    1    1   56   76
   1  44   NA   NA   16   55
   3  13   NA   NA   NA   NA
  55   6    2   NA   56   10
   4  33    2   NA   45   9
   2  66    1   NA   12   45
  72  99   NA   NA   NA   NA
  12  11    2    2   30   12"
)
```

Method 1:

```
df %>%  
  transform(age1 = case_when(age1 > age2 ~ age1, 
                             TRUE ~ age2), 
            age2 = case_when(age2 > age1 ~ age2, 
                             TRUE ~ age1))
```

Method 2:

```
df %>%  
  transform(age1 = pmax(age1, age2), 
            age2 = pmin(age1, age2))

  ID1 ID2 sex1 sex2 age1 age2
1   8   9    1    2   44   11
2  17   7    1    1   76   56
3   1  44   NA   NA   55   16
4   3  13   NA   NA   NA   NA
5  55   6    2   NA   56   10
6   4  33    2   NA   45    9
7   2  66    1   NA   45   12
8  72  99   NA   NA   NA   NA
9  12  11    2    2   30   12
```